# Dynamically push new column in 2D array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to add new values in a 2D array dynamically using jQuery with the following code:

```
var disabledTime = [[]];
var index = 0;

$("#addTimeSlot").click(function(){ 
    // do some stuff here...
    disabledTime[index].push($('.slotTime').last().prev().val());
    disabledTime[index].push($('.slotTime').last().val());
}
```

when `index` is `0` everything is ok, but after incrementing it gives me an error: "undefined is not an object".

I need to create something like `[['1','2'],['3','4']]` where elements are added dynamically. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because when the `index` is not zero, the element in array is `undefined`. Initializing the element to empty array will work.

```
var disabledTime = [[]];
var index = 0;

$("#addTimeSlot").click(function () {
    //do some stuff here...

    // Check if the element at `index` is not undefined.
    if (disabledTime[index] === undefined) {

        // Initialize to empty array.
        disabledTime[index] = [];
    }

    disabledTime[index].push($('.slotTime').last().prev().val());
    disabledTime[index].push($('.slotTime').last().val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because only index 0 has an array.

You cannot push to an index that is not an array itself.

Just start with an empty array, then push an array to that first:

```
var disabledTime=[];
    var index = 0;
    $("#addTimeSlot").click(function(){ 
    //do some stuff here...
 disabledTime.push([]);
 disabledTime[index].push($('.slotTime').last().prev().val());
 disabledTime[index].push($('.slotTime').last().val());
```

Comment: the 5th line should be disabledTime.push([]);

Answer (score 0):

your array is `[[]]` meaning it contains an empty array at 0 and
at all other indexes it is undefined

basicly do : `array[index] = []`